# How much bonus damage would you deal with a lich bane, a trinity force and an iceborn gauntlet if you used an ability then auto attacked

Tags: league-of-legends

All 3 of these items have the "spellblade" passive, but they all have different effects.
Trinity force deals bonus physical damage equal to 200% of your base ad.
Lich bane deals bonus damage equal to 50+75% of your ap
Iceborn gauntlet deals 125% of your base ad to enemies around your target, plus creating a slowing field

So if I have all three will I do (in addition to my normal auto attack damage) 50+75% of ap+200% of base ad+125% of base ad to enemies around your target? As well as creating the slowing field?

Will it be a random one of these items that proc?

Or will the first item I buy proc?

Or will it be something different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Spellblade](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spellblade#Spellblade) is a unique passive, this means that multiple copies do not stack.
The order of priority is Lichbane, Trinity Force, Iceborn Gauntlet, Sheen.

Note: The AOE slow on Iceborn Gauntlet is Icy, rather than Spellblade. This is not mentioned in the tooltip. This means that it does stack with Lichbane/Triforce, but does not stack with Frozen Mallet.